# В одном sql-запросе запросить 2 типа данных

Tags: sql, php, mysql

Всем привет! У меня есть sql-запрос вида:

```
SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `id` = '".str_clean($_GET['id'])."'"
```

Мне нужно с помощью одного запроса вытащить как все категории из таблицы, так и одну категорию id которой совпадает с **str_clean($_GET['id'])**

Т.е должно получиться что-то вроде:

```
SELECT * FROM `categories` && SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `id` = '".str_clean($_GET['id'])'"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделать то это можно, но вот какую смысловую нагрузку будет нести ваш запрос?
В чем смысл объединять **полную** выборку с выборкой по **id**, если первая железобетонно включает в себя второе?

Код на [SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24249/1)

Comment: @ua6xh а как потом массив распарсить?

Comment: @Lektor - какой массив? Результат запроса? Так вы же как-то до этого выводили результаты запроса, правильно? точно так же и здесь.

Comment: @ua6xh Да верно, PHP

Comment: @Lektor - Ну, у вас же есть написанный код для доступа к БД? Если нет, то [изучайте][1] как это делать.

[1]: http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php

Comment: Какой-то бред. Вообще разумный ответ привел @Node_pro, но если так уж хочется скинуть выбор активной категории на СУБД - то просто нужно добавить к выборке `IF`-поле.

Answer (score 2):

А если сделать `SELECT * FROM categories, и потом сделать проверку с помощью php

```
if($row['id'] == str_clean($_GET['id']))
//...
```